# css link visited background

Tags: css, hyperlink, background, visited

For some reason visited background no change to gray color.
Anyone know how to fix?

```
a:link {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(241,231,103);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(241,231,103) 0%, rgb(241,231,103) 32%, rgb(248,217,54) 73%, rgb(253,208,22) 100%);
}

a:visited {
  background-color: gray;
}

a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(253,208,22) 0%, rgb(248,217,54) 27%, rgb(241,231,103) 68%, rgb(241,231,103) 100%);
}
```

HTML file, I need to use css in my task

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">one</a>
<a href="#">two</a>
<a href="#">three</a>
<a href="#">seven</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML as well?

Comment: Try to set a default `background color` of your link, check answer

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="http://www.wp.pl">one</a>
<a href="#">two</a>
<a href="#">three</a>
<a href="#">seven</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a default background color to your link, for example `white`

```
a{
  background-color: white;
}
```

then

```
a:visited {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly with background set to a simple color but We need to set gradient for a background exactly same as above and then link visited set to a  gray color.

Answer (score 0):

`a:visited` is not a full proof way to do this. You can make it with a short jquery.

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('a').css('background-color','gray')
})
```

Above method is perfect for your problem :)

Comment: I need to use css in my task

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

use this

Comment: Please add some explanation instead of just ordering the OP to `use this`

Comment: with above code you will define a background and then `a:visited` will also work without defining background first it will not take in `a:visited` also

Comment: Works perfectly with background set to a simple color but We need to set gradient for a background exactly same as above and then link visited set to a  gray color.